# ruby nokogiri not reading my xml file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an metadata.xml file that has :

```
<MediaItem ActualEndTime="8/2/2017 5:05:01 PM" ActualStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:01 PM" Clip="False" ClipEndTime="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" ClipParentId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ClipStartTime="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" CreatedDate="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" DateAdded="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" Duration="01:04:59.8290000" FileFormat="0" FileSize="0" Genre="Interview" GuideEndTime="8/2/2017 5:00:00 PM" GuideStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:00 PM" MovieId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" MovieYear="0" NumParts="0" OriginalAirDate="8/2/2017 12:00:00 AM" OriginalFileSize="3636725627" PartNum="0" RecordingType="Episodic" ShowSqueeze="True" TargetEndTime="8/2/2017 5:05:00 PM" TargetStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:00 PM" UserId="" VideoHeight="0" VideoWidth="0" />
```

How do I parse it with ruby and nokogiri?
I've tried :

```
f = File.open path
puts "f  : #{f}"
metadata  = {}
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
puts "doc : #{doc}"
p = doc.xpath("//ActualStartTime")
puts "p : #{p}"
puts "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

but I get this output :

```
f  : #<File:0x00000002755c40>
doc : <?xml version="1.0"?>
p : 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I am missing? I want to get ActualStartTime value, Duration value and Genre value.

**update**

```
metadata  = {}
f = File.read(path)
puts "f  : #{f}"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
p = doc.xpath("//@ActualStartTime")
puts "p : #{p}"
metadata['Duration'] = doc.xpath("//MediaItem/@Duration")
puts "metadata['Duration']  : #{metadata['Duration']}"
```

output:

```
f : <MediaItem ActualEndTime="8/2/2017 5:05:01 PM" ActualStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:01 PM" Clip="False" ClipEndTime="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" ClipParentId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ClipStartTime="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" CreatedDate="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" DateAdded="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" Duration="01:04:59.8290000" FileFormat="0" FileSize="0" Genre="Interview" GuideEndTime="8/2/2017 5:00:00 PM" GuideStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:00 PM" MovieId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" MovieYear="0" NumParts="0" OriginalAirDate="8/2/2017 12:00:00 AM" OriginalFileSize="3636725627" PartNum="0" RecordingType="Episodic" ShowSqueeze="True" TargetEndTime="8/2/2017 5:05:00 PM" TargetStartTime="8/2/2017 4:00:00 PM" UserId="" VideoHeight="0" VideoWidth="0" />   
p : 
metadata['Duration']  :
```

Answer (score 3):

You're [opening the file](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-new), but you're never actually reading the file contents (and also not closing the file after). You can read the file through

```
begin
  file = File.open './metadata.xml'
  f = file.read
ensure
  file.close
end
```

or through one of the shortcuts:

```
# closes file after block finishes
f = File.open('./metadata.xml') { |f| f.read }
```

or, since reading is such a common thing, you can use [`File.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-c-read)

```
f = File.read('./metadata.xml')
```

and now Nokogiri will read `f` just fine, though you'll need to use

```
p = doc.xpath("//@ActualStartTime")
```

since it's an attribute.

Comment: ...Or if you need to make a more specific search, `"//MediaItem/@ActualStartTime"`

Comment: @Simple Lime thanks but the solution is partially working. I updated the question.

Comment: @Tom Lord answer is not working.  I updated the question.

Comment: @mamesaye `.xpath` returns a list of `Nokogiri::XML` objects. You can call `.map(&:value)` to convert them to the plain text values.

Comment: @mamesaye yeah that might be it...I just copied your updated code, and set the path variable to point to a file containing the XML you posted and ran it, and see `p : 8/2/2017 4:00:01 PM
metadata['Duration']  : 01:04:59.8290000` being output, so I'm not sure what's different...maybe what version of Ruby/Nokogiri are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 and nokogiri 1.6.7.2

Comment: yeah don't know what to tell you, the code you have posted above works with the file you gave us. Justed tested on ruby 1.9.3p125 with Nokogiri::VERSION =>  "1.6.7.2". I can't reproduce your issue.